# How to checkpoint a delta table manually?

Tags: delta-lake

Delta Lake creates a checkpoint automatically per 10 version. Is there any way to create checkpoint manually?

Answer (score 5):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog 
DeltaLog.forTable(spark,dataPath).checkpoint()
```

Comment: I was unable to find the DeltaLog library/package in pyspark. Can someone point it out?